# Issue displaying ImageMatrix data in Java

Tags: java, machine-learning

As it stands I have two classes my ImageMatrix class and my ImageMatrixDB class, these should essentially build a 8×8-pixel matrices into an array to be manipulated later. I am using some datasets which I hope to apply some mahcine learning algorithms too.  (See the [data description](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/optdigits/optdigits.names) and [sample dataset](http://www.cwa.mdx.ac.uk/csd3939/coursework/cw2DataSet1.csv).) As it stands the java files look like so:

**ImageMatrix.java**

```
public class ImageMatrix {
    int[] data;
    int classCode;
    public ImageMatrix(int[] data, int classCode) {
        assert data.length == 64;
        this.data = data;
        this.classCode = classCode;
    }

    public int[] getData() {
      return data;
    }

    public int getClassCode() {
     return classCode;
    }
}
```

**ImageMatrixDB.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



public class ImageMatrixDB implements Iterable<ImageMatrix> {
    private List<ImageMatrix> list = new ArrayList<>;

    public static ImageMatrixDB load(File f) throws IOException {
        ImageMatrixDB result = new ImageMatrixDB();
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            for (String line; null != (line = br.readLine()); ) {
                int lastComma = line.lastIndexOf(',');
                int classCode = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1 + lastComma));
                int[] data = Arrays.stream(line.substring(0, lastComma).split(","))
                                   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                                   .toArray();
                result.list.add(new ImageMatrix(data, classCode));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public Iterator<ImageMatrix> iterator() {
        return this.list.iterator();
    }

}
```

My issue stems from outputting the data in readable format. I was wondering if someone could walk me through what my main should look like to output the data as I keep getting thrown errors when trying to load the file.

Thanks again.